# Twitter - Follow followers of a user using python

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to automate a few things for my twitter account,
Is it possible to follow the followers of a selected user via a python script ?

Comment: could you narrow your question? what have your tried? there are Python API >> http://scalien.com/documentation/scaliendb/twitter_tutorial_python.html and http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/ so; yes, you are likely to build a Python script that will do it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you even can rely on third party applications that can do this for you: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter/1.6.1

The other solution is to rely on their API and make the correct HTTP calls there by yourself.